# Using Swift to disable sleep/screen saver for OSX

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

**I'm looking for a way to disable sleep mode and screensaver through my application using Swift.** I know this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126953/how-to-disable-the-screen-saver-display-sleep-on-mac) has [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460033/what-is-the-correct-way-to-prevent-sleep-on-os-x) asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596319/how-to-programmatically-prevent-a-mac-from-going-to-sleep), but none of the answers are current (at least for Swift; I don't know about Objective-C).

I originally thought to use `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().extendPowerOffBy(requested: Int)`, but according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/extendPowerOffBy:), it is currently unimplemented.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you happened to find a solution to this? For UIApplication, this can be done: `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`, but `isIdleTimerDisabled` isn't a member of `NSApplication`. I'd be happy if you found a solution.

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately no I haven’t.

Answer (score 17):

I recently came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975149). It links to [Q&A1340](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html) at Apple, and translates listing 2 into Swift.

I refactored it into some different code, that shows how you can use them throughout the [`RunLoop`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop), for instance. I did check the code, and it works.

```
import IOKit.pwr_mgt

var noSleepAssertionID: IOPMAssertionID = 0
var noSleepReturn: IOReturn? // Could probably be replaced by a boolean value, for example 'isBlockingSleep', just make sure 'IOPMAssertionRelease' doesn't get called, if 'IOPMAssertionCreateWithName' failed.

func disableScreenSleep(reason: String = "Unknown reason") -> Bool? {
    guard noSleepReturn == nil else { return nil }
    noSleepReturn = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep as CFString,
                                            IOPMAssertionLevel(kIOPMAssertionLevelOn),
                                            reason as CFString,
                                            &noSleepAssertionID)
    return noSleepReturn == kIOReturnSuccess
}

func  enableScreenSleep() -> Bool {
    if noSleepReturn != nil {
        _ = IOPMAssertionRelease(noSleepAssertionID) == kIOReturnSuccess
        noSleepReturn = nil
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

The [Q&A1340 answer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html) also points out that using `NSWorkspace.shared` should only be used to support OS X < 10.6.

Comment: This seems to be working for me.  I think it's noteworthy to state that you need to import IOKit and IOKit.pwr_mgt for this to work

Comment: Also, this solution works for Mac Catalyst apps as long as the code above is contained in the appropriate architecture target tags.

Comment: `kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep` is now deprecated. Use `kIOPMAssertPreventUserIdleDisplaySleep` instead.